# How do I solve this: $\sigma(n)=\frac{3n(n-1)}{2}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integers, divisor-sum

I would like to know the relationship between power of sum divisor function $\displaystyle\sigma(n)=\sum_{d|n} d$ and pentongonal numbers then i'm seeking to solve this equation :$$\displaystyle\sigma(n)=\frac{3n(n-1)}{2}$$

**Note:** For instance i have $n=2$ is a solution ,are there other ?

Thank you for any help !!!

Comment: Pentagonal numbers are of the form $\frac{3n(n-1)}{2}$.

Comment: sorry , just a wrong typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the sum of divisors function $\sigma(n)$ must be less than or equal to the sum of all the numbers less than or equal to $n$, and $\sum_{i=1}^n i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and $3n(n-1) > n(n+1)$ if $n>2$ there are no solutions other than 2.

Perhaps you meant to ask when $\sigma(n)=\frac{3k(k-1)}{2}$ for some $k$.  In other words, when is $\sigma(n)$ pentagonal?

Answer (score 0):

Since
$\sigma(n)
< e^{\gamma}n\log\log n +\dfrac{0.6483 n}{\log\log n}$,
there are at most
a finite number,
probably none,
of solutions.

See
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function